# Compilation of SCSS file with selector with background-color assigned to result of arithmetic operation on a variable produces an error

Tags: html, css, sass

In an SCSS file, I've assigned a variable, $bgCol, to a shade of grey and I have six id selectors- each of whose background-color property is assigned to a multiple of the $bgCol. When I compile the SCSS file, I get an error message saying that the arithmetic computation operation (e.g. $bgCol * 1.5) is undefined.

The relevant html is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div> 
    <div id="d3"></div> 
    <div id="d4"></div> 
    <div id="d5"></div> 
    <div id="d6"></div> 
</div>
```

The relevant sass code is (with error-producing line followed by a comment):

```
$bgCol: #111;

.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

%abox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: $bgCol;
    margin: 20px;
}

#d1 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 1.5; //this line produces the error on compilation; i imagine other id selectors with this multiplication computation would produce the same error
}

#d2 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 2.5;
}

#d3 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 3.5;
}

#d4 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 4.5;
}

#d5 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 5.5;
}

#d6 {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: $bgCol * 6.5;
}
```

The desired behavior is for each successive inner div to be a lighter shade of grey than the one before (i.e. the div w/ id 'd1' is the darkest, the div w/ id 'd2' is a bit lighter, and the div w/ id 'd6' is the lighest). How can I fix the error I get when compiling the SCSS file and get the desired color scheme?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply do arithmetics on colors in SASS.

How about

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  #d#{$i} {
    @extend abox;
    background-color: scale-color($bgCol, $lightness: (($i + 0.5) * 10%));
  }
}
```

This will expand into 6 selectors, from `#d1` to `#d6` each `@extend`ing the `abox` mixin and having a brighter background color as the ID increases.

Please note the differences between `lighten` and `scale-color` from the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/color#lighten).

Comment: I get the error "The target selector was not found." at the @extend abox line